# How to use loadmultiplier

Tags: webrtc, sip, ims

I saw loadmultiplier is providing **free** of cost for functionality testing of **SIP,WEBRTC,IMS and JSON**.
I wanted to use for functionality testing of **SIP**.

Could you please tell me the procedure to use the loadmultiplier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please click [here](https://loadmultiplier.com/node/179) to get loadmultiplier installation related information.
For more details you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464046/1861447).

Comment: I wanted to use all packages in a single machine. Is it possible to install all packages in a single machine ? Is there any sequence I need to follow for the packages during installation ?

Comment: @LandyTorres : Yes, you can install all packages in a single machine. There is no need to follow any sequence for installation. It is advisable to use minimum 4GB RAM in that machine.For more details you can click [here](https://loadmultiplier.com/node/179).